# How to provide the functionalities/features of an android app without the user having to explicitly install it

Tags: android

I'm trying to provide certain functionalities for an android phone that could help people in times of emergencies. (These functionalities are dependent on the phone's sensors.) The only/main approach to achieve this seems to be that of developing an app (and I am currently in the process of developing one). But, what concerns me is that the number of people using an application specifically for emergency purposes is quite low. Even if they do install, when "Insufficient Memory" pops up, an emergency app is very likely to be booted out of the phone.

Are there other ways of providing the functionalities/features of an emergency app, without the users having to explicitly install the app? Or should I just stick with the app?

Certain OEMs provide emergency features as part of their settings. Like for example, in a Samsung phone you can toggle to enable the "Send SOS messages", and then, in case of an emergency, press the power button thrice. In what way could I achieve the same?

Any help would be much appreciated...
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Android Instant Apps seems like it might be good fit https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Without a proper application installed in user device, you cannot provide the functionality you want.

OEM's also have their applications build and packaged with the system image. If you want it, you need to be in contact with them to include your application in new devices.